# How does parrying work for a Dual-wielding character in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm a bit of newbie in when it comes to character builds. I decided to create an imperial male char which reached level 27.

I chose a dual wielding warrior build (obtaining the Blades's armor, Dragonbane one hand sword, Dawnbraker one hand sword and a spare Elven dagger with paralysing effect)

Could you guys help me to know if the parry/block is functionally working now for a dual wielding char, because it's quite hard for me to restart the game and create a new male warrior char from scratch, focused on a two-handed build or a different build ?

My current char it's a hybrid imperial male warrior char with skill points invested in one hand / dual wielding / blocking / restoration / and heavy armor mostly, it acts as a hybrid dual wielding/paladin.

Comment: Could you trim down useless information from this post? It takes a while to get to the point.

Comment: Races in Skyrim, unless you're going for speedruns or something, are mainly chosen for aesthetic reasons. The racial skills have long cooldowns and aren't very impactful. You can always use console commands (assuming you're playing on PC) if you really want to change your character/build, but don't want to start over.

Comment: Most of this post is irrelevant to the question.  Trim out everything that isn't related to the question you want answered.  If you want to know if dual wield works, just talk about that.  Don't ask for opinions.  Then you'll have a much better question for people to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your reply guys, I will separate my questions into different topics as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parrying or blocking doesn't work when dual wielding.

[Source](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Block#Defensive_Blocking)

> You cannot block if you have a weapon or spell equipped in your left hand.

There's almost nothing that is exclusive to dual wielding.  In the one-handed combat perk tree, there are only two perks that have anything to do with dual wielding.

There's nothing stopping you from just picking up a shield and start blocking.

Comment: Thank you for your accurate reply guys, I will separate my questions into different topics as requested.

Comment: This is the most accurate site for further questions concerning defensive blocking. http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Block#Defensive_Blocking

Comment: @CostinGiumba Uh, that link is in my answer already.

Comment: Sorry, added it in case someone needs to quickly find stats and more thorough details about defensive blocking skills.